# Parsing a filename and directory from a single parameter

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a script that will create an XML document for use in further automation. Among other things, the `dropDir` and `fileName` should be parameters. But since these are both going to be required and the file will always be in the `dropDir`.

I'm wondering if there's a way that I can combine these two parameters into a single parameter, and then just parse out the file from the single string?

So for example, the user would call the script:

`.\iAmAScript.ps1 -path C:\prodfiles\settings.xml`

Internally in iAmAScript, it would logically take the following actions:

```
If (![System.IO.File]::Exists($path)){
    New-Item $path -type file
    $dropLoc = $path.<some method returning C:\prodfiles\>
    $fileName = $path.<some method returning settings.xml>
}
```

I'm just not quite sure how to do this in the context of Powershell, is the best way to try to figure out a way to use the `LastIndexOf` method within Powershell to truncate everything to the left of the last \?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Split-Path`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849809.aspx) to get these components:

```
$file = $path | Split-Path -Leaf
$dir = $path | Split-Path -Parent
```

The .NET methods are as follows:

```
$file = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($path)
$dir = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($path)
```

You could also get the item and use its properties:

```
$item = Get-Item -Path $path
$item.Name           # the file
$item.DirectoryName  #the directory
```

This object can be passed to most cmdlets that accept file parameters, and it exposes additional methods. To do this though, the file has to exist first, so you'd have to create it and then get the item but this might be useful later in your script.

Comment: Holy crap that is way too easy.